# Tkinter screen is showing up black despite recently working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am running python 3.7.6 with tkinter on pycharm as my IDE. I had an application that was working recently. Without making any changes to the code tkinter has started showing up with a black screen when the app opens. In the back ground the widgets brought into the app seem to working as I can see responses coming through on the command line. This has happened with all of the tkinter applications I have built out.

The code for the app is very simple:

```
import tkinter as tk
from frames.chat import Chat

class Messenger(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("1200x500")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.chat_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.chat_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        message_fetch = ttk.Button(
            self.chat_frame,
            text="Fetch",
            command=self.hello_world, # basic command that gets users 
                                      # name and prints it out
        )
        message_fetch.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="EW")


root = Messenger()
root.mainloop()
```

What could be leading to tkinter showing up with the black screen?

I have tried reinstalling python 3.7 and changed to python 3.8 both with no luck. At the time I was trying to get the pyinstaller tool to work on making the app an executable which required making some changes to the packages in pyinstaller due to issues with locating the tcl/tk modules. I did not think those would lead to this issue.

Comment: Don't ask the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438267/how-to-resolve-tkinter-black-screen-with-functioning-buttons-in-background) twice.  You should update your old post with more details and reopen it instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I did change the post add some of the detail for the code as updated here. I did not see an option to reopen the old post.

Comment: If adding `self.config(bg='red')`, do you see a red background window?  If yes, it may be related to your system theme.

Comment: no when I change it to red the background stays the same. I had actually just built up a whole app using tkinter that was working as expected with tall of the design and functionality. The issue came about at some point when I was trying to create the executable for the application using pyinstaller. I had followed these steps which finally allowed me to create the executable https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3753.

I have been troubleshooting this issue for days after working on this project for a few weeks.

Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Update: I fixed ti by restarting the gpu processes on my chromebook